# upgrade-insecure-requests directive works but a warning is displayed anyway

Tags: google-chrome, http, https, content-security-policy, mixed-content

I'm loading external content on my web site and I have no control on this content.
My web site is served over HTTPS but some of the external URLs use HTTP.
So I added the `upgrade-insecure-requests` policy.

This works and I can see in the Chrome DevTools that all external resources are served over HTTPS.

But recently I started getting this warning:

[image]

Also, when such content is loaded, the little padlock on the left of the address bar is removed.

Is this warning only there to tell me "*hey, I did my job but you should do something about those insecure URLs*" or is there something else I'm missing?

NOTE: It works as expected with Firefox: HTTP becomes HTTPS, no warning and the padlock remains.

Comment: The message seems to indicate for that resource the upgrade to https failed — the browser wasn’t able to upgrade the request to https. That’d happen if the resource isn’t actually available at an https origin, but only at an http origin. You can check that manually by taking the http URL, changing the http part to https, and pasting it into your browser address bar. If you get a 404 or if it redirects you back to the http URL, then you know that it’s not actually available at an https URL.

Comment: That's a good idea but I already checked that and the resource can indeed be served over HTTPS. And I'm not sure DevTools shows `HTTPS` when the upgrade fails...

Comment: Seems than that meta tag is deprecated in all new browser versions.

Comment: Which meta tag? `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"...>`? I seriously doubt it's deprecated. Plus it's an old issue that I didn't reproduce lately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems that it was a false alarm from Chrome since this warning has disappeared.